# How to change the href of a wicket container?

Tags: java, routes, wicket, wicket-6

With wicket 6.18.0 and Java 8.
I have a simple wicket panel:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<wicket:panel>
  <wicket:container wicket:id="editSection">
       <div class="item"><a wicket:id="edit"><wicket:message key="edit" /></a</div>
  </wicket:container>
</wicket:panel>
</html>
```

And in my webpage I have something like that:

```java
public class MainPage extends WebPage {
   public MaintPage() {
      WebMarkupContainer edit = new WebMarkupContainer("editSection");
      edit.add(new AjaxHashLink("edit", "edit"));
      add(edit.setVisible(true));
   }
}
```

But on the url I have `#edit` at the end of the page when I click on my edit link due certain to the `AjaxHashLink`.

But I would like it to be `/edit`, but so I am thinking there's something that can be done to modify the `href` of the link.

Comment: See the source code of AjaxHashLink, copy it and adapt it!

Comment: BTW what is \ in `\edit` ? Maybe you mean `/` ?!

Comment: Yes, `/edit` I updated my question. Ok we had a custom implementation of it that I didn't dig into. I'll see what I can find, would you know the name of the boolean or method making it a markup tag with `#` instead of a `/` ?

Comment: I guess AjaxHashLink overrides method `onComponentTag(ComponentTag)` and calls `tag.put("href", "link#hash")`

Comment: It worked but I've forsaken the idea since our wicket routing is based on hash, changing that broke everything ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's to route to an external resource, you may use the [RedirectToUrlException](https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/apidocs/8.x/org/apache/wicket/request/flow/RedirectToUrlException.html) in this case which

> Causes Wicket to interrupt current request processing and send a redirect to the given url. Use this if you want to redirect to an external or none Wicket url. If you want to redirect to a page use the RestartResponseException

You could use [RequestCycle](https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/apidocs/8.x/org/apache/wicket/request/cycle/RequestCycle.html) to get help resolve the url of the current wicket page and throw the exception:

```java
throw new RedirectToUrlException(currentUrl + "#edit");
```